# are there video training or tutorial videos on gwt + app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

i want to learn it! please if you know good videos, post links. Want to do it with Java, since I know already a little bit about it.

Comment: Are you going to be using Python or Java for App Engine?

Comment: In hindsight, that was a stupid clarification to ask for.

Comment: no problem ;) no question can be stupid, a friend told me

Comment: Sam, actually that question is legit. One could assume Java and that would be a safe assumption, but many do use GWT without Java on the backend. So kudos for forcing clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any videos that combine GAE and GWT, but they're fairly orthogonal anyway. Check out the videos that that Google have posted:

- [Overview of Google Web Toolkit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ezm7MJeMa9M)
- [Campfire One: Introducing Google App Engine (pt. 1)](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=C62453DBECDB1FAD&search_query=GoogleDevelopers+Campfire+One) [Python]
- [Google App Engine - Early Look at Java Language Support](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3GT4-m_6RQ)
- [Campfire One: App Engine's 1st Birthday](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=DFDBB63922B90A70)
- [Sessions at Google I/O](http://code.google.com/events/io/sessions.html) Also has many videos on GAE and GWT.
  For GAE I'd recommend:

  - [From Spark Plug to Drive Train: Life of an App Engine Request](http://code.google.com/events/io/sessions/FromSparkPlugToDriveTrain.html)
  - [The Softer Side Of Schemas - Mapping Java Persistence Standards To the Google App Engine Datastore](http://code.google.com/events/io/sessions/SofterSideofSchemas.html)
  - [Offline Processing on App Engine: a Look Ahead](http://code.google.com/events/io/sessions/OfflineProcessingAppEngine.html)

It's worth looking at some of the python videos (particularly the 1st birthday and Google I/O ones) to see what features the Java version will be getting. It's worth

- [Best practices for writing scalable applications](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/overview.html) covers more advanced topics.

Answer (score 1):

List of GWT Google I/O sessions is [here](http://google-code-updates.blogspot.com/2009/06/google-web-toolkit-at-google-io.html). I'd highly recommend a couple:

- [Google Web Toolkit Architecture: Best Practices For Architecting Your GWT App](http://code.google.com/events/io/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html)
- [Measure in Milliseconds: Performance Tips for Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/events/io/sessions/MeasureMillisecondsPerformanceTipsWebToolkit.html)

I'd also recommend downloading a pdf of session presentation first to quickly assess if it's of interest to you - it will save you a lot of time that way.

Comment: That first link has a nicer summation of the GWT sessions at I/O than the one I provided. The only one it doesn't list is *Using the Visualization API with GWT and Other Advanced Topics* : http://code.google.com/events/io/sessions/UsingVisualizationApiGWT.html

Answer (score 1):

The blog [GWT & App Engine Project](http://gwtappengine.blogspot.com/) details the full development of an application with GWT and App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

http://gogotraining.com/training/courses/22/google-web-toolkit/

this is free video course on GWT, just one need to create FREE account